# Nuxtjs composition API reactive not working on nested object

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-composition-api

I would like to update the nested reactive object, the value of `root.data.name`.  I've tried uses the $nuxt.$set and Object.assign, but none of it works.
My code as below:

```
<template>
 {{ root.data.name }}
</template> 
<script>
   import { defineComponent, reactive } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api'
   export default defineComponent({
       setup() {
          const root = {
             data: reactive({
                name: 'default'
             })
          }

          return {{ root }}
       }
   })
</script>
```

> Below is the code I used to update the object.

```
1: $nuxt.$set(root, 'data', {name: 'updated name'})

2: root.data = Object.assign({}, root.data, { name: 'updated name' })
```

Although the value has been updated to the object, but it does not reflect to the template(html).

Comment: Is this the actual code you have? root isn't returned from setup, it's not used in the template

Comment: `return {{ root }}` is not valid syntax. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem. Also it isn't shown where exactly you update the object which could be a part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `root` itself is not reactive.

It should be:

```
  const root = reactive({
     data: {
        name: 'default'
     }
  })
```

Then both `root.data = ...` and `root.data.name = ...` will result in an update.